# jQuery Validate и неактивная кнопка отправки

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация, jquery-validation

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в jQuery Validate создать условие, по которому если есть хоть один не валидный `<input>`, то кнопка отправки не активна.
В JavaScript не силен и в документации jQuery Validate, тоже не могу найти...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 $("#reset-form").validate({
  rules: {
   emailaddress: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }

  },
  messages: {
   email: "Please enter a valid email address"
  }

 });
  
  $("#emailaddress").on("blur", function(){
    if($("#reset-form").valid())
   {
       $("#btn-reset").removeAttr("disabled");
   }
 }); 
});  // end doc ready
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form action="" id="reset-form" class="reset-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
        <input class="text-input" type="email" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row arrow">
        <input id="btn-reset" type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn-disabled btn-reset button button-blue" disabled="true">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а не подскажите где я косячу? https://ru.files.fm/u/gvymktah